# C# OleDB Excel Reader Object to Array

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I have an excel which has 70k rows and I will do some calculations with data.

I wrote this code to get excel values into var object which type is {double}. I want to unbox it into an array to work with values or are there any other solutions to work with it.

```
private string FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Master.xlsx");

    public string ConnectionString(string FileName, string Header)
    {
        OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Builder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
        if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToUpper() == ".XLS")
        {
            Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0";
            Builder.Add("Extended Properties", string.Format("Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR={0};", Header));
        }
        else
        {
            Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
            Builder.Add("Extended Properties", string.Format("Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR={0};", Header));
        }

        Builder.DataSource = FileName;

        return Builder.ConnectionString;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString(FileName, "Yes") })
        {
            con.Open();
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [INJECTION Data$]", Connection = con })
            {
                OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
                var rowDataArray = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => new[] { x[0] });
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Try :  double a = (double)dt.Rows[5].ItemArray[3];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @jdweng

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection { ConnectionString = ConnectionString(FileName, "Yes") })
        {
            con.Open();
            //using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { CommandText = "SELECT F1, F2, F3 FROM [Sheet1$]", Connection = con })
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand { CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [INJECTION Data$]", Connection = con })
            {
                OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(dr);
                var rowDataArray = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => new[] { x[0] });
                double[] a = new double[dt.Rows.Count];

                for(int i = 0; i <dt.Rows.Count ; i++)
                {
                    a[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0]);
                    
                } 
            }  
        }
    }
```